# Deserialize JSON in VB.net WebMethod

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, deserialization

I have a JSON array built in javascript that I would like to pass into a VB.Net WebMethod and deserialize so I can loop over the items in the JSON array.

Following is an example of the JSON. The JSON may have one or more items in it, in this case there are three items. I would like to deserialize these JSON arrays so I can loop over them in VB.Net.

```
 jsonArrayString =   { "reportArray": [{ "reportName":"volumeSST",  "reportQuarter":"9/30/2013" , "dateTime":"1385430869676" , "muLevel":"false" , "cumulative":"false" ,
    "perAcre":"perAcreFalse" , "reportLevel":"TRACT" , "qryFeature":"11000110000000" },
    { "reportName":"volumeSST",  "reportQuarter":"9/30/2013" , "dateTime":"1385430869676" ,
    "muLevel":"false" , "cumulative":"false" , "perAcre":"perAcreFalse" , 
    "reportLevel":"TRACT" , "qryFeature":"11000180000000" }, { "reportName":"volumeSST", 
    "reportQuarter":"9/30/2013" , "dateTime":"1385430869676" , "muLevel":"false" , 
    "cumulative":"false" , "perAcre":"perAcreFalse" , "reportLevel":"TRACT" , 
    "qryFeature":"11000190000000" }]}
```

This is the javascript I use to pass the JSON into the WebMethod:

```
 nameOfAsmx.deserializeJson(jsonArrayString)
```

This is what I have so far to try and deserialize the JSON. What I would like to do is loop over the items in the JSON and store them in some sort of object:

```
 Public Function deserializeJson(jsonArrayString As String) As String
        Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim rpts = js.Deserialize(Of rptsClass)(jsonArrayString) <<I am not sure if this is correct.

        'NEED SOME CODE TO LOOP OVER rpts AND GET THE ITEMS (i.e. reportName, report Quarter etc.)

    End Function
```

Here is the class I built to store the JSON items so I can pass the values into other VB.Net functions;

```
Public Class rptsClass
    Public reportName As String
    Public reportQuarter As String
    Public dateTime As String
    Public muLevel As String
    Public cumulative As String
    Public perAcre As String
    Public reportLevel As String
    Public qryFeature As String
End Class
```

So my problem is that I can not figure out how to loop over the deserialized JSON and/or extract each item from the individual arrays. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is using http://james.newtonking.com/json an option?

Comment: That looks like a definite possibility but I still am unsure how to store multiple item arrays so I can loop over them one at a time. Thanks.